# custom roles and permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am newbie in django and drf, so this is the place where I think I could be helped.

I am building a office attendance system.

Now here the users are 1. Operational Manager(OM) 2. Admin 3. staff 4. CEO. OM can creates a new user and assigns whether it is admin or staff or ceo.  Admin, Staff and CEO have their own permissions.

My questions is how to assign these roles and permission to the types of user in django rest framework.
I had seen the drf documentation on custom permission which says to extend BasePermission class and implement 2 methods.

My requirement is new user doesn't make registration by themself but OM creates a new user for them.

Edit 1:

I have implement this way. Will this work ?

model :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = {
    ('admin', 'Admin'),
    ('staff', 'Staff'),
    ('om', 'OM'),
    }
    user_choice = CharField(choices=user_type, blank=True, max_length=255)
```

serializer:

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
groups = GroupSerializers(many=True)
user_type = serializers.CharField()
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name','address','contact', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'branch', 'groups', 'user_type')

def user_group(self, data):
    user_type = data.get("user_type", "")
    email = data.get("email")
    user = User.objects.get(email = 'email')# get user object from post request
    if user_type == "admin":
        grp = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Admin')
        user.group.add(grp)

    elif user_type == "staff":
        grp = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Staff')
        user.group.add(grp)

    else:
        grp = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='OM')
        user.group.add(grp)
```

view:

```
class UserCreateView(ModelViewSet):
model = User
serializer_class = UserSerializers
```

Comment: probably, use another model `UserPermission` to set a permission type when a new user is created.

Comment: even take a look at [this](https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-role-permissions).

Comment: I didn't get how to use another model `UserPermission` to set permission? 
And is it not possible without using any 3rd party library ?

Comment: It is definitely possible without a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should decide which access controll app you want to use. Here you can fine a good comparision: https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2016/controlling-access-a-django-permission-apps-comparison/

For me using Native Django permissions with groups assigned to users and @permission_required decorator is enough.